# Before and After psuedo selecter not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Ive gone and created a custom built HR but for some reason the contents of the before element are behind the double lines in Chrome and Edge. Working perfectly in Firefox... Here is my code...

```
.dividerHR {
  float:left;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
  border-top:double medium #999;
  color:#999;
  text-align:center;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 5%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8)
 }
.dividerHR::before {
  content:'< Coding Poetry />';
  background:#181818;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:-12px;
  font-size:12px;
  padding:0 0.25em; 
  text-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8)
 }
```

Many thanks.
this is it in Chrome...
[image: hr in chrome]

And this is it in firefox...
[image: hr in firefox]

Comment: Working fine on chrome and Edge

Comment: Really @Vikas. what are you seeing as the contents are showing behind the 2 hr rules in chrome myself. Have a look at the screengrabs above.

Comment: z-index:1 on the before element?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to class .`dividerHR` and change `position:relative` to `absolute` on `.dividerHR::before`

Here is the updated solution:

```css
.dividerHR {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: double medium #999;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: relative;
}

.dividerHR::before {
  content: '< Coding Poetry />';
  background: #181818;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)
}
```

```html
<div class="dividerHR"></div>
```

Note: @Phillip Dews your css code as it is working fine on my chrome and Edge browsers.
but not working on your side so i have modified your css as above:

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the position of the before element to absolute, and then position with right and top:

```
.dividerHR::before {
content: '< Coding Poetry />';
background: #181818;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
right: 111px;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 0 0.25em;
text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by positioning.

```
.dividerHR {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    border-top:double medium #999;
    color:#999;
    text-align:center;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 5%;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8)
}
.dividerHR::before {
    content:'< Coding Poetry />';
    background:#181818;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:0 0.25em; 
    text-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8)
}
```